# Convert 24 Hour Time in to 12 Hour Time in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime-conversion

I want to convert 24 Hour time into 12 Hour AM/PM time.
e.g:- How to convert date 2012-03-20T22:30:00.000+05:30 to to 2012-03-20 10:30 PM??

I have extratced the date but its in 24 Hour time. I though used SimpleDateFormater but still for **12.30 it is showing 00.30 and not 12.30 PM**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html has all the formatting options

Comment: @StuartSiegler please don't link to outdated api doc (current version is jdk7 :-)

Comment: @kleopatra  good catch...  Update for v7...  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the new java.time package in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.ForID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2012-03-20T22:30:00.000+05:30", timeZone );
Java.util.Locale locale = java.util.Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("IN").build();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "SS" ).withLocale( locale).withZone( timeZone );
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String dateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a").format(new Date());
```